# How do I count the Sundays in a month and select third one?

Tags: sql-server

I have this table :

```
 Date                  month                DayOfWeek
2014-01-01              1                        3
2014-01-02              1                        4 
2014-01-03              1                        5
2014-01-04              1                        6
2014-01-05              1                        7
......                .....                   .......
2014-02-01              2                        8
......                .....                    .....
```

I want to get all third Sunday of the Month so :

```
Date                 month                      
2014-01-19            1                             
2014-02-16            2
```

I started by doing:

```
SELECT CAST(
        CASE
            WHEN [DayOfWeek] = 7
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS bit) as Result, [date], [month]
FROM mytable
```

Which give :

```
Result                   date                  month
0                       2014-01-01               1
0                       2014-01-02               1
0                       2014-01-03               1
0                       2014-01-04               1
1                       2014-01-05               1
....
```

So It is giving me all sunday and my initial idea was to count when Result is 1 for each month and get the date of the third one

How can I did that in sql server ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. The 3rd Sunday, has to be between the 15th and the 21st only.

```
SELECT CAST(
        CASE
            WHEN [DayOfWeek] = 7 AND DatePart(day,[Date]) between 15 and 21
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS bit) as Result, [date], [month]
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Haha, about 10 times better and less complex than my solution, plus one.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
select
    a.[Date],
    a.[Month]
from (
    select
        [Date],
        [DayOfWeek],
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [DayOfWeek], [Month] order by [Date]) as DayOfWeekCount,
        [Month]
    from mytable
) a
where
    a.[DayOfWeek] = 7
    and a.DayOfWeekCount = 3
```

EDIT: just saw you already had DayOfWeek as a field in your table, so no need for DATEPART at all.

Comment: Be careful relying on `DATEPART`. It's non-deterministic, based on the value of [`DATEFIRST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0):

The following script will give you all third Sundays in a given period:

```
USE TEMPDB

DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EndDate DATE

SET @StartDate = '2000-01-01'  
SET @EndDate  = '2040-12-31'  

IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..#Date') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Date
IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..#Date') IS NULL CREATE TABLE #Date (Date DATE)

INSERT INTO #Date VALUES (@StartDate)

WHILE @StartDate < @EndDate

BEGIN
INSERT INTO #Date

SELECT DATEADD (DD, 1, @StartDate) AS Date

SET @StartDate = DATEADD (DD, 1, @StartDate)

END;

WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT *,  
          CASE WHEN DATEPART (DW, Date) = 7 THEN 'Sunday' ELSE NULL END AS DayOfTheWeek
    FROM #Date AS D
)
, CTE2 AS 
(
    SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR (Date) * 100 + MONTH (Date) ORDER BY Date) AS RowNumb
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE DayOfTheWeek = 'Sunday'
)

SELECT * FROM CTE2 WHERE RowNumb = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by using a row_number partition like below.

```
Declare @table1 As table
    (
     Date varchar(14),
     month varchar(15),
     DayOfWeek varchar(15)
    )


BEGIN
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-01-01',1,1)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-01-02',1,2)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-01-03',1,3)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-01-04',1,4)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-01-05',1,1)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-01-06',1,2)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-01-07',1,3)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-01-08',1,4)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-01-11',1,1)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-01-12',1,2)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-01-13',1,3)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-01-14',1,4)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-01-15',1,1)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-01-16',1,2)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-01-17',1,3)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-01-18',1,4)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-02-01',2,1)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-02-02',2,2)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-02-03',2,3)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-02-04',2,4)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-02-05',2,1)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-02-06',2,2)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-02-07',2,3)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-02-08',2,4)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-02-11',2,1)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-02-12',2,2)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-02-24',2,3)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-02-14',2,4)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-02-15',2,1)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-02-16',2,2)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-02-17',2,3)
Insert Into @table1(date,month,DayOfWeek) values('2014-02-18',2,4)

END

Select Date,Month from (
Select *,row_number() over (partition by DayOfWeek,month order by Date) as seqnum from @table1) t2
where seqnum =3 and Dayofweek=3
```

Output

```
Date    Month
2014-01-13  1
2014-02-17  2
```